# Using response objects from third party api calls

Tags: api, web-applications

When creating a web application, if we use third party api calls , which themselves provide response objects, is it a good idea to directly use those response objects in the view /model? Or do we need to create a model object that copies the data from these reponse objects, just so that they are decoupled from the third party objects? Is this decoupling required always even when there is no other data attribute to add , other than the already existing data in the response object? Also these response objects seem to have no setter methods but only read methods? Does this information alter the design decision is any way?
What is the good practice here?

Answer (score 0):

I would not have dependency on external response objects while building the model objects. If the model object needs attributes from the response, I would pass the attributes instead. This helps in mocking the model objects during testing without much hassle.

When it comes to the view objects, I would think it to be fine to depend on the response objects to extract attributes from them during rendering.

My two cents!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just wanted to know, what if the reponse object had a lot of custom objects, would the right thing to do be to recreate my own replica versions of these custom objects in the model? It would be really helpful if you can share your thoughts on this.

Comment: Certainly not as it seems like the model is heavily dependent on the response object hierarchy. Would you be able to provide a concrete example from your domain about such a dependency?

Comment: I would not be able to share any code as it violates our firm's policy. However, I will try to elaborate. The response objects have some custom objects which are well defined in terms of equals,hashcode etc. When I use the response objects to construct my model, those are the same kind of objects that I see fit as attributes of the model. My dilemma is whether to use the reponse objects directly and pull the necessary details from the reponse objects custom objects or create my own custom objects which will kind of mirror the response custom objects except that it will be decoupled

Comment: I also wanted to add, that there might be another way of obtaining the same model objects , using a different api(internal service). So I do want to have a common object which can be populated with objects from the 3rd party api or internal service depending on whats needed in that use case. Hence while I feel decoupling is a good thing by writing my own objects, I do feel uncomfortable replicating those same objects , in my package. It feels like I am violating DRY principle. Appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: I agree with your second point where if the response object hierarchy is long/big enough, there is no point in mirroring that entire hierarchy and write methods to copy data between the two. In that case, it makes sense for the model to be dependent on these response objects.